# Making the first cell of a UITableView different to every other cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a table view, which is all working well enough but now I would like to have the first cell be an 'unlock' button for the remainder of the cells.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [currentPack count] + 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Row is %i", indexPath.row);

    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        SoundCell *cell = [SoundCell dequeOrCreateInTable:soundsTable];
        cell._NameLabel.text = @"Unlock This Pack;
        [cell._startButton setAlpha:0.0];

        return cell
    }
    else
    {
        SoundCell *cell = [SoundCell dequeOrCreateInTable:soundsTable];
        cell._NameLabel.text = [currentPack objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];

        return cell
    }
}
```

Now it kind of works, the first cell IS different to the others, and looks exactly as it should. My problem is that for some reason some of the later cells use the

```
[cell._startButton setAlpha:0.0];
```

part even though indexPath.row is not 0 when they are made. It doesn't happen to every cell, just intermittent ones, occasionally if I scroll the table up and down a lot then other cells will pick up this problem too. In every other way the table works fine, selecting a cell triggers the correct response etc.
Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? It seemed like it would be very simple to implement originally...

Thanks

Comment: I bet `dequeOrCreateInTable:` uses the same reuseIdentifier for both cells. Anyway, if the alpha value is the only difference you could just put `[cell._startButton setAlpha:1.0];` into the `else`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a different reuse identifier for the two cell types so that they don't mix when reused.

Or add the following line to the rest of the rows:

```
[cell._startButton setAlpha:1.0];
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm officially an idiot :-) I knew it would be something simple that I'd missed.

Comment: Haha, we all are at one time or another!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting hit by cell caching.  If you're going to call setAlpha on some cells, set it on all of them so that you don't end up with a stale value from an existing cell.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to create a separate instance of the SoundCell and store it as i-var. Just configure it once and return for row index 0. For the rest of rows return your reusable 'usual' cells.